# How can I store the result of .each() into localStorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

Here is my code:

```
localStorage.setItem('qandaInputsValue7', $("#ask_q_tags span:first-child, #ask_q_tags span + span").each(function() { return $( this )[0].outerHTML }));
```

The result is:

[image]

As you can see It is an object which isn't useful.

---

The expected result is: *(which should be as the value of that key in localStorage)*

```
<span>something</span><span>something else</span>
```

See? I need to make a combined string of `return $( this )[0].outerHTML` to set it into localStorage. How can I do that?

---

Noted that neither `JSON.stringify()` nor `.get()` won't work.

Comment: use `map` instead of `each`

Comment: give use the html dom plz

Comment: Use `map` and then `JSON.stringify`

Comment: @gurvinder372 Still it is a `Object`

Comment: @stack you need to use `get` after `map`

Comment: @gurvinder372 Now the result is like this: `<span>something</span>,<span>something else</span>`. Any idea how can I remove that middle `,` ? Because I want to push it into the DOM and that `,` is redundant.

Comment: @stack You're asking several questions at once. Break this up into parts, and each part has a simple answer you can easily find on Google or using the search here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map` instead of `each`, and then `get` and `join`

```
localStorage.setItem('qandaInputsValue7', JSON.stringify( 
       $( "#ask_q_tags span:first-child, #ask_q_tags span + span" ).map( function() { 
           return $( this )[0].outerHTML 
       }).get().join(""); //get and join here
));
```

No need to use `JSON.stringify`

```
localStorage.setItem('qandaInputsValue7', 
       $( "#ask_q_tags span:first-child, #ask_q_tags span + span" ).map( function() { 
           return $( this )[0].outerHTML 
       }).get().join(""); //get and join here
);
```

Comment: Thank you. The only problem is, when there isn't any element, the value of local storage will be `""`. The expected result is *nothing*.

Comment: @stack You can check the length of string before setting the same to localstorage

Comment: Isn't there something like `trim()` in JS ? (I'm actually a PHP guy)

Comment: `trim` will not trim an empty string to `null` or *nothing*.

Comment: well the result of your code isn't an empty string. It is a string contains two characters of `"`. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ns55S.png

Comment: can you try getting the value of `join` and tell me its `length`? I have added an update.

Answer (score 3):

`.each()` only performs the iterative logic, and does not return anything. What you are looking for is to use `.map()` and combine it with `.get()` to retrieve the actual output. Finally, you will need to convert the returned array into JSON so that it can be stored as plain text:

```
var htmlToStore = JSON.stringify(
    $("#ask_q_tags span:first-child, #ask_q_tags span + span")
        .map(function() {
            return this.outerHTML;
        })
        .get()
);

localStorage.setItem('qandaInputsValue7', htmlToStore);
```

Note that instead of using `$(this)[0].outerHTML` to refer to the original DOM node, you can just use `this.outerHTML` :) the `htmlToStore` will be an array, so if you want a true string, you will have to collapse the array using `.join('')`.